# ng-repeat (key,value) in json and then ng-repeat the value

Tags: angularjs

Why the ion-item will increase infinitely?

The json allItems like this:`{'tag1':[],'tag2':[],'tag3':[]}`
,every time change slide each array will add 10 data,but the array is increase infinitely.

```
<ion-slide id="{{key}}" style="width:100%;" ng-repeat="(key,value) in allItems" ion-slide-tab-label=“{{key}}”>

    <ion-content style="width:100%;">
      <ion-refresher pulling-text="下拉刷新" on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
      <div>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left"
                    ng-click="detail(item.url,item.docid,item.title,item.imglink,item.openid)"
                    ng-repeat="item in value track by $index">
            <img src="'https://'+{{item.imglink}}" alt="" />
            <h2 ng-bind="item.title"></h2>
            <span ng-bind="item.sourcename"></span>
            <span ng-bind="item.date"></span>
            <span ng-bind="item.tatalComment"></span>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
      <ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" ng-if="more" on-infinite="getMore()" distance="1%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-slide>
```

Comment: the ion-infinite-scroll has been always called,why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear. If you provide js part i can help correctly but my opinions are:

1. You are using infinite scroll in ng-repeat this is wrong. Every time you are adding  it creates infinite scroll again.
2. You forgot to broadcast scroll completed?

   ```
   $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
   ```